# .NET Framework Dependency appxmanifest

Tags: desktop-bridge

I am in process of prepping my Windows Desktop app for upload to the MS Store. I have a (fully functional) MSI installer for my app and attempted to use the Desktop App Converter (DAC) but experienced an error and have not gotten past it yet. So I decided to give manual package (appx) creation a try and it went well since I was able to install my app using the package I created. But I have a question about how to handle my .NET Framework dependency in the package. My MSI Installer has the '.NET Framework version 4.7.1' as a prerequisite so that it gets downloaded and installed (from MS, if not already installed). My question is how to handle the prerequisite in my package. I'm assuming it would go in the AppxManifest.xml under Dependencies where I currently have (note I removed the brackets so my code would display here)...

Dependencies
TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14316.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.16299.309" /
  /Dependencies

...but I am unsure of the syntax to add .NET Framework 4.7.1 so that it gets properly installed (if not already there) on target systems for my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app has 4.7.1 as a prerequisite, they will need to set their minversion to 16299 (Fall Creators Update).

In general, you cannot redist .NET with your app package, as it comes with the OS. But if you require a specific version, you need to make sure the minversion matches the update of Win10 that includes that specific version. You could use this table to look it up: [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies).

Comment: What happens if the client/s then upgrades to the next Windows 10 version with .net 4.8, will an application compiled for 4.7.1 run on 4.8?

Comment: Yes, all 4.x updates are compatible in-place upgrades.