# How to specify a .net dependency in a UWP project?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

I have a UWP app that uses a desktop extension to call a .net application. Since .net is not additive (4.7.1 does not include 6) - how do I verify that my .net application (which is mine, I can target any .net version) can run on the target computer? How do I get the target to download the appropriate .net version if it's not there already?

Comment: Any time I've tried to run a program that required a .NET version I didn't have, the OS automatically prompted a download.

Comment: @SeanO'Neil Yes. But this is a simple UWP app (not .net) which happens to call a .net app. The UWP app does not automatically confirm that .net is installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET Framework Dependency appxmanifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466874/net-framework-dependency-appxmanifest)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't redist .NET with your app package, you use the version that is in the box. For this to work you need to specify the correct OS minversion in your appxmanifest. Note that Versions 4.7.x are in place updates for 4.6. All you need to make sure is that the OS minversion specified in your appxmanifest matches the minimum version of .NET that your app requires to be in the box. You can find the mapping from OS version to NET version here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies

For example, if you are targeting NET 4.6.2, then you specify 14393 (Anniversary Update) as your OS minversion.

If you are targeting 4.7.1, then you need to specify 16299 (Fall Creators Update) as your OS minversion. Your app won't be able to run on earlier versions of Windows 10.