# Does Microsoft Store automatically install a .Net framework?

Tags: windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge, windows-10-desktop, appxmanifest

I'm now using Visual Studio 2022 to recompile a DLL project for a Microsoft Store App (desktop-bridge win32). Visual Studio while upgrading recommends me to use .Net 4.8 framework.

I'm looking at the .NET framework versions for various Windows version on this page:

[.NET Framework versions and dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/versions-and-dependencies#:%7E:text)

That means someone using my app on Windows 10 1803 will not have .Net framework 4.8 by default. So do I have to declare my min version in manifest file according to that page? Or, alternatively will the Microsoft Store automatically update the .Net framework for that user before installing the App?

What would be the proper recommended min version or build with a particular .Net framework strategy here?

Comment: Also found a good answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466874/net-framework-dependency-appxmanifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I remember it correctly, when users download your app from the Microsoft Store, it will automatically download all the dependencies.

As mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/gdk/_content/gc/packaging/packaging-framework-packages):  When the user installs your app from the Microsoft Store, it detects the dependency and ensures that the framework package is made available to the app.

If the framework package is already installed on the user’s device, no further action is necessary. Otherwise, the Microsoft Store triggers the installation of the framework package before proceeding with the installation for the app that uses it.

Comment: That document link is very useful. Thanks!

Comment: However, that document does not give an example on how to specify dependency on a .NET framework, for example, 4.8.

Comment: Also found a good answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466874/net-framework-dependency-appxmanifest